# Is there a way to avoid using a timer after setting an element size?

Tags: angular, promise, callback, settimeout

This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do...

In the code snippet below, I want to set a div element to a new size and then display the size of the element. If I don't use a timer, the old size is displayed not the new size.

Is there a promise or callback that I can hook into instead of using a timer here?

Much thanks - Jon

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div 
      style="background-color: bisque; height:250px; width: 350px; position:relative;"> 

      <div 
        #sizeableDiv
        style="background-color:cornflowerblue;" 
        [ngStyle]="{'height':divHeight, 'width':divWidth}">
      </div>

      <div style="position:absolute; left:10px; bottom:10px">
        <button (click)="setDivSizeNoTimer()">Set Size no Timer</button>
        <button (click)="setDivSizeWithTimer()">Get Size with Timer</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild("sizeableDiv", null) sizeableDiv: ElementRef; 

  title = 'angular-dom-promise-q';
  divWidth:string = "100px"; 
  divHeight:string = "100px"; 

  // 
  // we want to set the div size and display the new div size 
  // 

  // this will display incorrect div grid size
  setDivSizeNoTimer() {
    this.divWidth = "200px";
    this.divHeight = "200px"; 
    this.getDivSize();
  }

  // this will display correct div size 
  // is there any way to do this without the timer? 
  setDivSizeWithTimer() {
    this.divWidth = "200px";
    this.divHeight = "200px"; 
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        this.getDivSize()
      }, 1 
    )
  }

  private getDivSize() {
    console.log('Div size: ', this.sizeableDiv.nativeElement.offsetWidth, this.sizeableDiv.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the element size, you can call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` to update the view synchronously:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

setDivSizeNoTimer() {
  this.divWidth = "200px";
  this.divHeight = "200px"; 
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this.getDivSize();
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oemql6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.